# How does the network traffic not intended for my nic even reach my nic?

Tags: networking, wireshark

I was reading that in order to capture traffic for more than just my machine I need to put the nic into promiscuous mode. By default the nic seems to filter out the packets which are not meant for it.

My Question is : How come my nic even receive traffic that is not intended for it? Isn't my router supposed to route packets only to the computer for which it is meant?

**Sorry - newbie here and this may be an absolute down votable question that I am asking.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer: It depends.  :)

[Wireshark Wiki: Ethernet capture setup](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Ethernet)  should be of help to get you started.

Comment: Thanks willyo. This page is very nicely written and helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I have heard that in case of wireless networks, the traffic takes multiple paths and the NIC combines these signals to form the original signal. So when a NIC sends something to the gateway it will send multiple signals and some if not all may even be captured by your packet sniffer.
Monitor mode also works like this

Answer (score 0):

You might be surprised by seeing traffic that you are not expecting but after you study this for a while each packet can typically be explained.

Some things to keep in mind are:

1. When capturing traffic with Wireshark or similar tools, the NIC is put into promiscuous mode which causes **ANY** traffic received by the NIC to be seen by Wireshark.
2. In some cases, a switch will send traffic on a link because it hasn't (yet) learned what link the traffic should be sent to.  So you might see a packet with an IP for a host that doesn't match your host.
3. A mis-configured host might be on your LAN which is trying to communicate with a host that is not reachable.  The switch doesn't know this and so it sends traffic to hosts in an attempt to find the host that responds.
4. A lot of broadcast traffic is seen that is not all destined for your host but the NIC still receives it.
5. Many years ago home networks used HUBs to connect multiple devices and HUBS broadcast **all traffic** to **every host** (it's just the way HUBs work).  Today's switches are much smarter than that and learn what hosts on each link and after they learn that they don't send data that is not intended for the link down the link.
6. When dealing with WIFI other factors come into play but since I haven't done enough WIFI packet capture, I'll leave that to others to answer.